# How to create Office UI in win form Using C#

Tags: c#, office-ui-fabric

I google a lot for a long time. I have no idea how to create OfficeUI in C# Win Form. Less article teach this.

I found this video. But it is presentation of the OfficeUI only. Actually, I really want to develop a Win Form like this.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dCTmWjN3WkA

any idea?

many thanks.

Comment: have a look at devexpress but it's not free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean you want to add an Office Ribbon Bar to a WinForms application ? If you google ".net WinForms RibbonBar" you will find a bunch of examples; for instance this CodeProject one; http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/364272/Easily-Add-a-Ribbon-into-a-WinForms-Application-Cs